# How can I set glm::vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f) as a value of an enum?

Tags: c++, enums

I want to have an enum which contains glm::vec3 "constants".

Currently I have an enum called "Axis", which contains X, Y and Z. and every time I use them I have to map them with a switch case into a glm::vec3 with corresponding values.

This is my Axis enum:

```
enum Axis 
{
    X,
    Y,
    Z
};
```

This is how I currently convert it to glm::vec3:

```
glm::vec3 angleVector;

switch (axis)
{
case X:
    angleVector = glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    break;
case Y:
    angleVector = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    break;
case Z:
    angleVector = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    break;
}
```

And this is how I want to use it instead:

```
enum Axis 
{
    X = glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    Y = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
    Z = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
};
```

I tried much things to get the glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) as a constant which my enum does accept, but nothing worked.

(

like this:

```
static const glm::vec3 vec3x = glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

and then:

```
enum Axis 
{
    X = vec3x
};
```

)

Comment: `enum` values can only be based on intrinsic types, which `glm::vec3` obviously isn't.

Comment: So there is no chance to archieve what i want?

Comment: No you cannot do that directly. You might consider using a `std::unordered_map<Axis,glm::vec3>` using `enum Axis { X, Y, Z };` to get rid of the switch though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yeah but it would be nice if it was a compile-time constant map.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException That could be done of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a namespace with static variables instead. Then you'll be able to use it roughly as you would with an enum.

```
namespace Axis
{
    static const glm::vec3 X = glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    static const glm::vec3 Y = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    static const glm::vec3 Z = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
};
```

If you want to pass it to a function, you could create a class. However, then you'd have to instantiate an object when passing it in.

```
class Axis
{
public:
    glm::vec3 X = glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glm::vec3 Y = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glm::vec3 Z = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
};
static const Axis euclidean_space_axis;

void DoStuff(Axis axis)
{
    std::cout << "X-axis: " << axis.X.x << ", " << axis.X.y << ", " << axis.X.z << "\n" <<
    std::cout << "Y-axis: " << axis.Y.x << ", " << axis.Y.y << ", " << axis.Y.z << "\n" <<
    std::cout << "Z-axis: " << axis.Z.x << ", " << axis.Z.y << ", " << axis.Z.z << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    DoStuff(euclidean_space_axis);
}
```

Comment: but then i cant pass it like a variable into funcitons or am i wrong?

Comment: @MaggieGrace Not the namespace, no. You'd have to pass in each separate variable. Or use them as globals.

Comment: @MaggieGrace You can of course pass these into a function expecting a `glm::vec3` type parameter.

Comment: @MaggieGrace You could create a class instead, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a table instead of switching:

```
enum Axis { X, Y, Z };
const glm::vec3 axes[] = { glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), 
                           glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 
                           glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)};
```

and then

```
Axis axis = ... whatever ...;
glm::vec3 angleVector = axes[axis];
```